# Laravel Chumper Datatable getting data into one datatable from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable, which contains data from more than one MySQL table.

I am using Chumper as I am also using Laravel, as far as I can see there is no examples using more than one sql table at one time.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class CRUDController extends BaseController {

public function instances(){

$query = EC2Instance::select('instance_id',


                    'public_dns_name',
                    'key_name',
                    'instance_type',
                    'launch_time'

                    )->get();

$c_num= Account::select('aws_account_id'
                    )->get();
$t_name= Tag::select('value'
                    )->get();


return Datatable::collection($query, $c_num, $t_name)

    ->addColumn('instance_id', function($model){
        return $model->instance_id ;
        })

    ->addColumn('public_dns_name', function($model){
        return  $model->public_dns_name;

    })
     ->addColumn('key_name', function($model){
        return  $model->key_name;

    })

     ->addColumn('instance_type', function($model){
        return  $model->instance_type;

    })
     ->addColumn('launch_time', function($model){
        return date('M j, Y h:i A', strtotime($model->launch_time)); 
    })

         ->addColumn('aws_account_id', function($model){
        return  $model->aws_account_id;
     })
        ->addColumn('value', function($model){
        return  $model->value;
     })

        ->searchColumns('instance_id',
                        'public_dns_name',
                        'key_name',
                        'instance_type',
                        'launch_time',
                        'aws_account_id',
                        'value'
                        )

        ->orderColumns('instance_id',

                        'instance_type',
                        'public_dns_name',
                        'key_name',
                        'launch_time',
                        'aws_account_id',
                        'value'
                        )
        ->make();
}
}
```

The `$query` values are fine and render correctly it is the `$c_num` and `$t_name` which are missing.

Comment: you can replace all your "addColumn" where you'er just returning a model attribute with ->showColumns("instance_id", "public_dns_name", "key_name", "instance_type", "aws_account_id", "value").

Comment: i can recommend you this video which might help answer some doubts
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9fao_5Jo3Y