# Laravel Routing to same view different function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to return values from a MySQL database into a datatable using Chumper. I am trying to obtain values from 2 tables; but I am having what I believe to be a routing issue as I do not know how to include 2 controller functions to the same view ie in my search view I want to render the result of 2 functions like : for a deeper understanding of what I am trying to accomplish see question : [Laravel Chumper Datatable getting data into one datatable from multiple MySQL tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601165/laravel-chumper-datatable-getting-data-into-one-datatable-from-multiple-mysql-ta)

```
Route::get('search', array('as' => 'instance.search', 'uses' => 'CRUDController@instances'));
Route::get('search', array('as' => 'accid.search', 'uses' => 'CRUDController@account_ids'));
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a single route will ever match any given URL requested of the system.  I believe what Laravel will do is choose the *second* one (as in the second definition will overwrite the first).

You have some options here.  All I can really tell from your question is that you want two methods to be executed when that route gets hit.  This is indirectly possible, consider:

```
Route::get('search', 'MyController@instances');

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function instances()
    {
        $mydata = $this->account_ids();
        $myotherdata = $this->getOtherData();

        return View::make('myview')
            ->with('mydata', $mydata)
            ->with('myotherdata', $myotherdata);
    }

    private function getOtherData() { /* ... */ }
}
```

This isn't really clean, though, and eventually will lead to convoluted controller logic which is an anti-pattern in MVC.  Fortunately, Laravel let's you use [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers), which can greatly clean up your controller logic:

```
public function instances()
{
    return View::make('myview');
}
```

Wow.  Nice and simple.  Now the view composer part:

```
// Inside of a service provider...
View::composer('search', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\AViewComposer');

use View;
class AViewComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('instances', $this->instances());
        $view->with('accountIds', $this->accountIds());
    }

    public function instances()
    {
        // generate your instance data here and return it...
        return $instances;
    }

    public function accountIds()
    {
        // generate your account id data here and return it...
        return $accountIds;
    }
}
```

You could take this a step further and inject another class into the constructor of this view composer to completely off-load the responsibility of determining what 'instances' and 'account ids' actually mean, should you need that same functionality elsewhere.  This will help you keep your code extremely DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You are having those 2 routes but with same domain so the second one is running over the second one.

Or you change the URL of on of them or you change the method for post instead of get